# How can I use Crystal Reports record selection to choose from a list AND included a specific field

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to figure out how to write a formula in the record selector that would allow me to select records in a specified list....but ONLY if there is also a specific record.

In My example.  I am pulling earnings codes for employees from specific payroll transactions.  For each Transaction date...each employee will have up to 10 codes.

I have my record selection set as this to narrow down the codes I want to see:

```
{UPCHKD.EARNDED} in ["01", "02", "BNSQT", "BVMT", "CASHBO", "FLAT", "HOL", "HOLPAY", "WAPFML"]
```

The issue is that I only want to see the first 8 codes IF there is also the WAPFML code.  I can't figure out how to tell the record Selector to pick records that have BOTH WAPFML and any of those other 8 codes.

```
{UPCHKD.EARNDED} in ["01", "02","BNSQT", "BVMT", "CASHBO", "FLAT", "HOL", "HOLPAY", "WAPFML"] and
{UPCHKH.TRANSDATE} in {?Beginning Check Date} to {?Ending Check Date}
```

I hoped to see only checks where the WAPFML code existed.  But I'm obviously returning checks that may not have that code.  Using Group selection doesn't work as then I don't see the lines for the other codes.

Comment: can you elaborate this line `The issue is that I only want to see the first 8 codes IF there is also the WAPFML code`

Comment: Hi!  Yes...I would like to return the detail of a paycheck ONLY if there are lines that include the code WAPFML and any of the other 8 in my selection formula.  As I don't want to see transactions that don't include WAPFML.  Was that more clear?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are grouping on {Employee_ID}, Add a group selection formula of MAX({UPCHKD.EARNDED}, {Employee_ID} ) = "WAPFML"

This takes advantage of the fact that "WAPFML" happens to be the largest alpha value in the set. If that is not the case, a more robust approach is to add the UPCHKD table a second time (with an alias), join on same Emp_ID to the first alias, and add a record selection condition on the 2nd alias forcing it to be "WAPFML"

Comment: Thank you for these ideas!  I tried both and couldn't quite get them to work.  Perhaps I'm not entering the group selection formula properly?  I am getting an error that the remaining text does not appear to be part of the formula.  So I'm missing something.    I entered:  MAX({UPCHKD.EARNDED}, {UPCHKD.EMPLOYEE} ) = "WAPFML"

Comment: Also...when I tried the alias.  All it did was duplicate each line...but did not clear out the lines where no WAPFML existed....

Comment: Hi!  I got the formula to work.  Needed MAXIMUM.  It still allows lines that don't include that Code to come up.  I think maybe it just isn't going to work!  LOL

Comment: Use MAXIMUM instead of MAX

Comment: Did you leave the record selection criterion to include only the desired 8 codes?

Comment: OH I GOT IT!  I was grouping by Employee and then transaction date.  I entered Maximum ({UPCHKD.EARNDED}, {UPCHKH.TRANSDATE}) = "WAPFML"  and took maximum of each transaction date and BOOM.  Which now makes all the sense in the world.  Thank you SO VERY MUCH for pointing me in the proper direction.

Answer (score 0):

OH I GOT IT! I was grouping by Employee and then transaction date. I entered Maximum ({UPCHKD.EARNDED}, {UPCHKH.TRANSDATE}) = "WAPFML" and took maximum of each transaction date and BOOM. Which now makes all the sense in the world. Thanks so much MilletSoftware for helping me!